# Swift2 JSON Parsing with multiple dictionaries

Tags: json, parsing, swift2

I have successfully read the data from the following site: http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/countries. I can see the values in the debug window. However, I am unable to iterate over the items. There are more than 200 items and I would like to iterate through them and print out their values (name, currency name, id, etc...)

The code to read the data:

```
func countryList() {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let jsonUrl = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/countries"

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary

            //let results: [String:[String:[String]]] = jsonData["results"]! as! [String : [String : [String]]]
            let results = jsonData["results"]!

            // iterate all items and print values
            // how ???
        } catch _ {
            // Error
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I have tried the following: `let results : [String:[String:[String]]] = jsonData["results"]!` however this does not work, and I would be surprised if it did :).

Any pointers?

using Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2

Result data returned with JSON (sample):

```
Country & Currency List{
"results":{
    "GQ":{
            "currencyId":"GQE",
            "currencyName":"Central African CFA franc",
            "name":"Equatorial Guinea",
            "alpha3":"GNQ",
            "id":"GQ"
        },
    "TD":{
            "currencyId":"XAF",
            "currencyName":"Central African CFA franc",
            "name":"Chad",
            "alpha3":"TCD",
            "id":"TD"
        }
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of key `results` is a dictionary, it can be enumerated with a simple `for .. in` loop.
`countrycode` is the key, `info` the value.

Downcasting a dictionary to `[String:AnyObject]` includes all forms of nested objects.

This code prints out the country code and the name of each item

```
do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! [String:AnyObject]
    let results = jsonData["results"] as! [String:AnyObject]

    for (countryCode, info) in results {
      print(countryCode, info["name"] as! String)
    }
  }
```

Be aware that there is no order because a dictionary is unordered by definition